# Android retrieving events from local device calendar

Tags: android, android-calendar

Am trying to fetch the events from device local calendar in android. Am using this below code for retrieving events from calendar.

```
cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars"),
               new String[] { "_id", "displayName" }, null, null, null);       
// Cursor cursor = cr.query(Uri.parse("content://calendar/calendars"), new String[]{ "_id", "name" }, null, null, null);

while (cursor.moveToNext()) 
{
    final String _id = cursor.getString(0);
    final String displayName = cursor.getString(1);
    final Boolean selected = !cursor.getString(2).equals("0");
    System.out.println("Id: " + _id + " Display Name: " + displayName + " Selected: " + selected);
}
```

But my app get crashed in this line:

```
cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(Uri.parse("content://com.android.calendar/calendars"),
           new String[] { "_id", "displayName" }, "selected=1", null, null);
```

What am did wrong in this above code. Please help me to solve this issue. I have mentioned below my crash log.

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: displayName: , while compiling: SELECT _id, displayName FROM Calendars WHERE (selected=1)
    at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:181)
             at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:137)
    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:358)
    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:312)
    at com.creagx.VideosActivity$4.onClick(VideosActivity.java:161)
          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3517)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14155)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4624)
             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:809)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:576)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)**
```

Answer (score 3):

Please use the standard Calendar Provider and it's parameters rather than strings. You are assuming that the table has a "displayname" column.

Refer to for proper [implementation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html)